# Is this considered a random/probability sample?

Tags: sample, survey-sampling

a company that conducts face to face surveys have described their sampling procedure as follows:

> We use a unique and rigorous sampling method - a form of random
>   location sampling, using a control method applied to field region and
>   sub-region over a robust number of sample points (typically 170-180)
>   to ensure we get a good geographical spread. We then set our
>   interviewer quotas for gender, age, working status and tenure to
>   ensure our sample is nationally representative - we use the CACI ACORN
>   geo-demographic system in the selection process.

Would this be a random or a probability sample? Or is it a non-probability quota sample? Or a combination of both? (is that possible?)

Comment: The market-speak in this description sounds wonderful, but when you try to understand what it's really saying, nothing definite is there.  The ultimate question comes down to *how* they "ensure our sample is nationally representative," but the quote offers no real information.  There's no way to tell what kind of sample it is.

Comment: @whuber  I don't agree that "nothing is there" or  that "there's no way to tell what kind of sample it is" in the quote provided. Among other things, the reference to the *CACI ACORN geo-demo system* is a cornerstone comment. CACI a canonical approach to sampling in marketing. In reading the Wiki statement about this technique, it is clear that a great deal of rigor goes into its development and implementation. On the other hand, I agree that the blurb is "market speak." They could have provided a much more detailed description of their process.

Comment: @DJohnson Sure--if you trust that these people "use" that system well.  But they are so vague about that, they could mean literally anything.  BTW, you misquote me: the omitted adjective "definite" is crucial to the original meaning of my comment.

Comment: @whuber  Agreed..."trust" is the key, operative word here. There is plenty of evidence out there to deny that basic construct when marketers are involved.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with @DJohnson -- this does not look like a probability sample -- simply because the probabilities of selection are not quantifiable for quota samples. The phrasing "unique and rigorous" is another obvious smell. Face-to-face surveys can be designed using the established sampling techniques (e.g., Kish's classic sampling book) based on the reliable ONS data, without the need to come up with anything "unique". In these samples, interviewers are instructed by the sampling statistician who to interview, rather than allowed to pick up somebody from the crowd (which is what quota sampling by location would eventually end up being) -- and the interviewers will probably pick up the easier-to-interview cases that way, biasing the sample.

That does not mean that the ultimate sample is awful. It may be reasonably close to the target population on demographics, so whatever is closely related to demographics may work out OK. But many behaviors are rather poorly explained by demographics, and nonprobability samples often have a poor record of tracking behaviors. Then again, for marketing purposes you may not need the fully rigorous sample if all you need is to figure out what audience your product should target.

For more information, you can check out the following reports by the American Association for Public Opinion Research, the leading professional society that deals with issues of survey methodology:

1. [Task Force on Non-probability Samples (2013)](http://www.aapor.org/AAPOR_Main/media/MainSiteFiles/NPS_TF_Report_Final_7_revised_FNL_6_22_13.pdf) -- of which quota sampling is an example.
2. [Task Force on Evaluating Survey Quality (2016)](http://www.aapor.org/Education-Resources/Reports/Evaluating-Survey-Quality.aspx) -- checklist of questions that a consumer of survey data should be asking.

Comment: I agree that the quote uses some regrettable language in "selling" their technique and that could be contributing to its misreading. Your key point seems to hinge on their use of the term "survey sampling." In reviewing the links you provided, the Task Force does come down hard on "simple survey sampling," but goes on to cite numerous instances where it can be and is employed, e.g., in sample matching. What the quote describes is definitely *not* "simple survey sampling" but, rather, a rigorous form of sampling based on the CACI Acorn system. In other words, all quotas are not bad or wrong,

Comment: as long as in the last step a random selection process is used. Clearly, that is being employed as described in the quote.

Comment: OK, give me a reference to a JASA or an SMJ or a JOS paper that spells out the probability structure of the CACI Acorn system. Without that, I only see handwaving.

Comment: Read the Wiki entry about it

Comment: Look, if you are happy with it as a marketing researcher, that's fine by me; gives you the bang for the buck. But it does not satisfy the definitions, that's all I am saying. Look up the definition of a measurable design in [Thompson's book](https://www.amazon.com/Surveys-Chapman-Monographs-Statistics-Probability/dp/041231780X). All steps have to be random, not just the last one.

Comment: We are not in agreement on your last point and it has nothing to do with marketing. There is much more controversy about sampling protocol than your citation either allows or suggests. I've taken classes with academics who were sampling theory experts and have unequivocally stated that, as long as the last step is random, then you can be comfortable that the design is probabilistic.

Comment: So I went back to the expert source of my response regarding the last step. Despite my distinct recollection regarding his comment, he no longer supports it and is in alignment with the views articulated in Thompson's book (among others). *Mea culpa*.